# After effects - keying based on saturation

Tags: colors, key, after-effects

In my video, I'm trying to achive something similar to "sin city effect" - leaving one color, while rest is desaturated. since my video isn't suppost to by just black and white with one color pushing out, I need to find a way to composite the color layer over the video, without changing its color.
Basicaly what I need to know is, wheather there is a way to key out everything, that has 0 saturation.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming. Please read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking. You should post this question [**here**](http://video.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Apply Leave color to your footage, choose the color you wanna leave and set amount to decolor to 100% and use hue to match color